# What namespace does global variables belong to, if we don't declare a namespace name explicitly for it?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Recently I am trying to be familiar with C++. And I am a little confused with the "Namespace" stuff. Here's a example code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace foo
{
  int value() { return 5; }
}

namespace bar
{
  const double pi = 3.1416;
  double value() { return 2*pi; }
}
int a; //what's the namespace it belongs to?
int main () {
  cout << foo::value() << '\n';
  cout << bar::value() << '\n';
  cout << bar::pi << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Above code shows two explicit namespaces: foo and bar. And both of them have some global variables in their scope. My question is for variable **a**, becuase we don't specify the namespace name for it, what namespace(or anonymous namespace) does it belong to? Or it has no namespace to attach to? If I want to use this variable **a** from other files, how do we specify its namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is in the [global namespace scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). If it isn't shadowed, and assuming you have included the right header files, you can simply refer to it as `a` in your other file. However, if it is shadowed, or if you just want to play it safe and refer to it explicity, you can refer to it as `::a`.

For example,

```
#include <header_for_a.h>

namespace B
{
 int a;//This now shadows the "a" from the global namespace.

 void foo()
 {
  a = 1;//This is referring to B::a;
  ::a = 2; // This is referring to "a" from the global namespace.
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int a
```

belongs to global namespace. That means another variable with same name in global namespace *could* buy you a linker error.

*If I want to use this variable a from other files, how do we specify its namespace?*

You can just enclose it in namespace. Generally a namespace should have all related entities in it. So, if you think it can be put inside already existing namespace then get set go.

Comment: probably wouldn't give a linker error. If you have another one in the same file you get a compiler error, otherwise you get undefined behaviour that often doesn't cause linker error.

Comment: So, that means linker would give a green signal if we try to define same variable in multiple translation units.

Comment: depends on the linker, but the C standard doesn't require to diagnose it and linkers often keep things to a minimum for various reasons